# What are the fractional octal and hexadecimal conversion specifier in C?

Tags: c, hex, printf, octal, conversion-specifier

I am aware that when using the `printf` function I can express the octal value of an integer with `%o` and its hexadecimal value with `%x`.
How can I represent a floating-point value as octal or hexadecimal, though?
When trying to use the same specifiers, Xcode 13.x predictably throws a warning telling me I am trying to use an integer specifier with a floating-point value.

How can I work around this?
Thank you

Comment: If you want to print an **octal** number the way `%a` prints a hexadecimal number, you can do the following: Build the hexadecimal representation using `sprintf(..."%a"...)`. `171.75` would result in `AB.C`. Convert each hexadecimal digit to 4 binary digits: `AB.C` becomes `10101011.1100`. Remove or add leading zeroes before and trailing ones after the decimal point so the number of digits before and after the point is divisible by 3. Convert 3 binary digits to octal. `010101011.110` becomes `253.6` which is the octal representation of `171.75`.

Comment: Thank you. How would I do this in code? Your procedure is what I would do "manually"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format a `float` or `double` in hexadecimal using `%a` or `%A` (to use lowercase or uppercase letters, respectively). There is no conversion specifier for octal for floating-point.

This formats the value. If you want to view the representation of the floating-point object, you should access its bytes using an `unsigned char *`, and then you can format those bytes using the `o`, `x`, or `X` conversion specifiers.